# context menu for listview does not fire the RightTapped event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have been working with c# for some time now but surprisingly I have never dealt with context menus before. I have a listView control in my universal windows 8.1 app. Now I am trying to get a context menu to popup for each item in the listView (they are all the same type of object and are added to the list as the user adds entries). I have run into several problems with this and have looked at code examples and they seem to be leading in different directions. Firstly when I right click on an item in the list it does not fire the ListView_RightTapped event.

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstvwHours" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="264" Margin="427,77,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="357" RightTapped="lstvwHours_RightTapped">
```

Secondly in Microsoft's context menu code example they say to use the PopupMenu class but in other code I've seen it coded into the XAML.

And lastly After the one context menu button is clicked I want it to fire a delete method.
private async void lstvwHours_RightTapped(object sender,

```
RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menu = new PopupMenu();
    menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Delete"/*do I put the method to call here?*/));
    var chosenCommand = await menu.ShowForSelectionAsync(GetElementRect((FrameworkElement)sender));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example.

In this case you can wire-up the commands that get invoked from your menuitem onto your view-model.

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem Content="One">
        <ListViewItem.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Insert"
              Command="{Binding DataContext.InsertQuery, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" 
              Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteQuery, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListViewItem.ContextMenu>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Comment: That's what I would have thought it would be, but the .ContextMenu property doesn't exist in universal apps xaml. Or at least I can't get it to work.